# How to make column on one sheet only contain values, or combinations of said values, present in another column?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets column where the only possible values should be combinations of values from another column. So in this image, the cell with product 4 would be rejected since it is not from column C

[image: Sample Google Sheet]

Normally, I would just use the data validation feature, but combinations of values such as "product 1, product 2" would also not be allowed since they are not "product 1" or "product 2" exactly and data validation only allows exact values from other columns.

I tried using a custom formula with Regexmatch, but I haven't managed to work it out as to only allow values from the specified column and had to resort to hardcoding it in, as such

```
=regexmatch(A1,"product 1"|"product 2"|"product 3")
```

but when I add a new value to the data column, I have to modify the formula again so it is not an optimal solution.

How Do I go about doing this now because I haven't found much info online?

Answer (score 1):

you can play this out like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))<>"", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ",")), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)), 
  REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ",")), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C))&",", "♦"), ))
 ,,999^99)), "where not Col1 contains '♦'", 0), ",$|, $", ))
```

[image: 0]